# Issue redirecting query string to path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect a get query parameter to a path and maintain the ability to use the GET parameter in the code.

I struggle to find examples excluding the file extension so perhaps this is what is throwing me.

I have tried the below code but not getting expected results from it?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/spares/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /spares/%1 [R=302,L]
```

For example:

mysite.com/spares/?pid=x

to

mysite.com/spares/x

**EDIT**:
Copy of .htaccess in /dev/ subdirectory.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect with pid
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s+spares/\?pid=(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /spares/%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally rewrite to ?pid=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^dev/spares/$ /dev/spares/?pid=%1 [NC,L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect with pid
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+spares/\?pid=(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /spares/%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally rewrite to ?pid=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^spares/$ /spares/?pid=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank-you, this only seems to work with numbers in the pid?

Comment: Because that was the case in your question code. You can change `\d` 2x to `.`

Comment: Thank-you. I understand now, my final question is adding a developer folder within the htaccess, mostly the first Rewrite Cond throws me, what do the `+` do?

`RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect with pid
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+dev/spares/\?pid=(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /dev/spares/%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# To internally rewrite to ?pid=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pid=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/dev/spares/$ /dev/spares/?pid=%1 [NC,L]`

Comment: Ok, just change the las one `RewriteRule ^dev/spares/$ /dev/spares/?pid=%1 [NC,L]` without first `/`

Comment: I still do not understand why it does not work, I have posted the full .htaccess and I am wondering if it is the rules at the beginning causing issues? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you have to place that before WordPress rules